# Здесь работает, здесь - нет

Tags: c#

Программа, написанная на С# 2013 Express, прекрасно работает на моем ПК (W 8.1) и у заказчика (W 7). Но на ПК в соседней комнате (W 8.1) выбрасывает необработанное исключение в момент открытия и обработки текстового файла.
Может быть дело в FrameWork?

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске. Текст ошибки в студию

Comment: Странно, моя программа в моей соседней комнате работает. Может быть, вы приведёте текст того самого необработанного исключения?

Comment: Стандартное сообщение о необработанном исключении. Природа его не раскрыта.

Comment: я знаю ответ: все дело в программе! информация 100%

Comment: Поставьте отладочные печати и снова запустите программу в соседней комнате. Так Вы поймете, до какого места программа добегает и откуда выбрасывает исключения. :-)

Comment: Я и так это знаю и указал в вопросе.

Comment: стандартное? Там весь стек вываливается- там много полезной информации

Comment: Напишите отдельную программу открытия и обработки этого текстового файла и снова запустите программу в соседней комнате. Так Вы поймете, виноват ли файл. :-)

Comment: Опечатайте соседнюю комнату, окропите дверь святой водой, посыпьте перед ней солью и сожгите (разработчика). Должно помочь (последнее).

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится!

Comment: Я специально написал про "соседнюю комнату", чтобы повеселить уважаемую нетребовательную аудиторию. Вижу, ЭТА цель - достигнута. К сожалению, ничего другого  в комментариях не обнаружено..

Comment: Хорошо, отвечу именно на заданный вопрос: Да, дело может быть в Framework.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Еще может быть что вы файл перебрасываете по сети, или с интернета качаете - у вас срабатывает code security, и приложение просто на диск не пускает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайди в ивенты операционной системы с компьютера на котором не работает твоя программа.

Там написана ошибка запуска твоей программы. Если внимательно почитаешь ошибку -- увидишь причину по которой отваливается программа.

Я, как сильный маг приблизительно 85го левела с прокачанным направлением "Оракул" вангую тебе, что причина кроется в том, что на компьютер не установлена та версия .Net framework которая использовалась при написании программы.

И если это так, то пути целых 2:

1. понизить версию .Net framework  в программе
2. установить на компьютер нужную версию .Net framework

Comment: [не установлена та версия .Net framework ] Если инсталляшка сделана, то она проверяет версию .Net и переустанавливает ее. Трудно предположить, что ТС переносит свои программы без инсталляшки. :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 а как по мне, то не трудно. :) Иначе он знал бы про то, что нужно кидать стектрейс ошибки в вопрос. :D

Comment: Ну не знаю... Все-таки у человека 2,688 репы на счету. Не новичок стало быть. :-)